# Read/write USB mass storage fail

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, ioctl

I am writing a program, which can read and write USB mass storage data via bulk point. I tried to claim interface by this command:

```
int n =0;
n = ioctl(usb_fd, USBDEVFS_CLAIMINTERFACE, &interface);
```

But it always got error with error code n = -1 (Device or resource busy).
So how can i fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Why you have closed your [previose question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278312/read-write-usb-fail) about the same problem?

Comment: I want to be sure that this isn't a duplicate question...

Comment: But this is actually the same question as it was, isn't?

Comment: Yes... it is the same ~

Comment: Stack Overflow is Q&A cite, not a simple forum. No needs to repeat question only for make it newer.

Comment: Thanks... Becasue i still haven't the solution for it yet.